# Bash - sort by first letter of file name

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm trying to write a command for mplayer that will play all the music files in a directory, in order.

```
alias mplay='mplayer -playlist <(find "$PWD" -type f|sort -n)'
```

This works fine if I am already in the directory I'm playing music from.  In fact, it even works if I'm in a directory back and I type 'mplay MusicFileDirectory' for instance.

However, the command breaks when I'm not in the directory I play from and the files are numbered 1, 2, 3 ... 10, 11 etc (instead of 01, 02 ... 11) - the 10, 11 files are now played before the 2nd file.

This is because sort is being applied to an expanded file path, ie MusicFileDirectory/1, so it does not sort numerically.

How would I get the sort command to only sort the final part of a file path, so I can type 'mplay /home/james/Music/MusicFileDirectory' for example and it only uses the names of the files in the directory to sort the playlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure it will work, but give sort -V a try.

**EDIT:** As jordanm notes, this is apparantly a newer GNU extension.

Comment: You should note that this is a newer GNU extension. The question is not tagged Linux.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.  Good extension, never heard of it before.  Presumably a BSD solution would be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Sort has options to specify a field separator(-t) and position(-k). Something like:
`sort -n -t/ -k2`.

That said, if you want a generic solution to work from any directory, I am afraid a single-liner alias would be too difficult (and complicated). You are better off with a tiny script, where you will first count the number of "/" in the path (say `x`), and then do `sort -n -t/ -k$((x+1))`